# Method "useTestNetwork" not present in Java SDK

Tags: transactions

I am trying to use the testnet for transactions but the call from the [docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html) Network.useTestNetwork() is not present in my SDK for Java. I am using version 0.13.0 for development. Was this deprecated and is there a new declaration for using the testNet?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the method [has been removed](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/index.html?org/stellar/sdk/Network.html) and the documentation was not updated. You should build a network object and then pass it to the [transaction builder constructor](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/Transaction.Builder.html#Builder-org.stellar.sdk.TransactionBuilderAccount-org.stellar.sdk.Network-).